# Bootstrap carousel multiple frames at once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, carousel, bootstrap-4

This is the effect I'm trying to achieve with Bootstrap 3 carousel

[image]

Instead of just showing one frame at a time, it displays N frames slide by side. Then when you slide (or when it auto slides), it shifts the group of slides like it does.

**Can this be done** with bootstrap 3's carousel? I'm hoping I won't have to go hunting for yet another jQuery plugin...

Comment: Sorry already adapted Bootstrap 4 but easy to change http://stackoverflow.com/a/42098033/4796923

Comment: There is a new solution to this problem using Ken Wheeler's Slick Carousel  that is easier to implement and more elegant than these ones. Please view @joshmoto answer with the full code here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263516/345605

Comment: @ganar thanks, I posted a Bootstrap 3 and 4 Slick solution here...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Can this be done with bootstrap 3's carousel? I'm hoping I won't have
>   to go hunting for yet another jQuery plugin

As of 2013-12-08 the answer is no. The effect you are looking for is not possible using Bootstrap 3's generic carousel plugin. However, here's a simple jQuery plugin that seems to do exactly what you want http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 237):

**Bootstrap 5** (Update 2021)

While the carousel is mostly the same in Bootstrap 5, the concept of `left` and `right` have changed to **start** and **end** since Bootstrap now has RTL support. Therefore the left/right classes have changed. Here's an example of the multi-item CSS for 4 items (25% width columns)...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Since jQuery is no longer required, we use vanilla JS to clone the slides into the `carousel-item` divs..

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
    // number of slides per carousel-item
    const minPerSlide = 4
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})
```

[Bootstrap 5 Multi-item Carousel Demo](https://codeply.com/p/0CWffz76Q9)

---

**Bootstrap 4** (Update 2019)

The carousel has changed in 4.x, and the multi-slide animation transitions can be overridden like this...

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(33.33%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-33.33%)
}
  
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Alpha.6 Demo](http://codeply.com/go/FrzoIEKCdH/bootstrap-4-carousel-multiple)
[**Bootstrap 4.0.0 (show 4, advance 1 at a time)**](http://www.codeply.com/go/3EQkUOhhZz)
[**Bootstrap 4.1.0 (show 3, advance 1 at a time)**](https://www.codeply.com/go/SgN7j7h4dV)
[**Bootstrap 4.1.0 (advance all 4 at once)**](https://www.codeply.com/go/HDu8lT7NxJ)
[**Bootstrap 4.3.1 responsive (show multiple, advance 1)**<kbd>new</kbd>](https://www.codeply.com/go/zjZsn1ly29)
[**Bootstrap 4.3.1 carousel with cards**<kbd>new</kbd>](https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8)

---

Another option is a **responsive** carousel that only shows and advances *1 slide on smaller screens*, but shows *multiple slides are larger screens*. Instead of cloning the slides like the previous example, this one adjusts the CSS and use jQuery only to move the extra slides to allow for continuous cycling (wrap around):

**Please don't just copy-and-paste this code. First, understand how it works.**

[**Bootstrap 4 Responsive (show 3, 1 slide on mobile)**](http://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH/multi-carousel-single-slide-bootstrap-4)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /* show 3 items */
    .carousel-inner .active,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example - **Bootstrap 4 Responsive (show 4, 1 slide on mobile)**](https://www.codeply.com/view/JEAsn1lz3a)
[Example - **Bootstrap 4 Responsive (show 5, 1 slide on mobile)**](https://www.codeply.com/go/UBE4KZIeSJ)

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Here is a 3.x example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/89193

You need to put an entire row of images in the item active. Here is another version that doesn't stack the images at smaller screen widths: http://bootply.com/92514

**EDIT** Alternative approach to **advance one slide at a time**:

Use jQuery to clone the next items..

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

**And then CSS to position accordingly...**

Before 3.3.1

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
```

After 3.3.1

```
.carousel-inner .item.left.active {
  transform: translateX(-33%);
}
.carousel-inner .item.right.active {
  transform: translateX(33%);
}

.carousel-inner .item.next {
  transform: translateX(33%)
}
.carousel-inner .item.prev {
  transform: translateX(-33%)
}

.carousel-inner .item.right,
.carousel-inner .item.left { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

This will **show 3 at time, but only slide one** at a time:

[**Bootstrap 3.x Demo**](https://www.bootply.com/DKihet1ZM9)

---

**Please don't copy-and-paste this code. First, understand how it works.** This answer is here to ***help you learn***.

[Doubling up this modified bootstrap 4 carousel only functions half correctly (scroll loop stops working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343385/doubling-up-this-modified-bootstrap-4-carousel-only-functions-half-correctly-sc/49343508#49343508)
[how to make 2 bootstrap sliders in single page without mixing their css and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450116)
[Bootstrap 4 Multi Carousel show 4 images instead of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631386/bootstrap-4-multi-carousel-show-4-images-instead-of-3/48631630#48631630)

Comment: Thanks. That does look a lot better... but feels a bit weird. scrolling to the left doesn't seem to work, as it scroll multiple blocks at a time, and the order seems off. Scrolling to the right works fine (though in the wrong direction). The issue I'm having with this is that it seems to create a lot of duplicates, which is not that bad... but not that good... so for every item I have (6 in your case), that script creates N duplicates (where N = blocks shown per frame).

Comment: @Skelly Should that same logic work if there're four elements? I tried to modify the bootply, but it didn't work the way I needed :(

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira, I've fixed the left scrolling bug. Checkout [the fork](http://www.bootply.com/mefnTHulXi) with the missing `.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%; }` style.

Comment: @Zentaurus, I know it is late, but check out [the four elements example](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/Dv9FF/). I've adapted Skelly logic for an [SOpt question](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26186/como-passar-de-um-em-um-elemento-no-carousel0).

Comment: Found why it doesn't work on > 3.3.0 it is due to the inclusion of translate3D, check the answers of Danijel and Michal Vrchota on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613271/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-display-two-items

Comment: I revamped the entire answer for 3.x and the new 4.x carousel

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Just a note it does not work on Bootstrap 4.1  here is an example where it does not work as expected https://www.codeply.com/go/abl0iCMUOE

Comment: @MikeA That doesn't work because it's not the correct CSS/JS as shown in the answer. It should look like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/RncxxzycWg

Comment: @Zim that demo keeps 1 slide visible. I am hoping to show 3 or 4 (as many as the screen fits) then show 1 item after that.

Comment: @Junior Exactly, in the latest version (4.3.1) the only thing that got it working for me was [the margin adjustment explained in another answer in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029749/1326147).

Comment: @Codeply-er all the links in the answer are broken. Are you able to update them please? Thanks.

Comment: @Codeply-er must have been Codeply! I was getting 500 errors for all of the links before. Thanks - great answer.

Comment: Can any one explain the CSS code for responsive carousel

Comment: @zim Thanks for your professional guidance
I'm working with version 5 and it worked great
I use this code to find the first active to be compatible with php

<? = (array_key_first ($ comments) == $ key)? 'active': ''?>

I hope it is useful

Answer (score 38):

All the above solutions are hacky and buggy. Don't even try. Use other libs. The best I have found - http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider
Works great with bootstrap, does not add junk html, highly-configurable, responsive, mobile-friendly etc...

```
$('.multi-item-carousel').lightSlider({
    item: 4,
    pager: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    slideMargin: 0
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very usefull lib :)

Comment: Some of these slider library indeed dwarfs what bootstrap, even 4, offers. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The slider duplicates slides. See example sliders soruce code on their website.

Comment: This is a dead project with too many open issues. (check their github)

Answer (score 21):

[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/show/) is a working twitter bootstrap 3.

Here is the **javascript**:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();

    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

And the **css**:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
.carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
.carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
.carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

You can see it in action at this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/)

The reason i added this answer because the other ones don't work entirely. I found 2 bugs inside them, one of them was that the left arrow generated a strange effect and the other was about the text getting bold in some situations witch can be resolved by setting the background color so the bottom item wont be visible while the transition effect.

Comment: thank you for sharing...i do see some flickering in firefox, however.

Comment: @paulalexandru how can I increase number of images in visible row ?

Comment: Well in case you have 4 items in your css you should change 33% with 25% and you have to make a little change in the javascript also. In case you don't manage to resolve that, post a question and i will post a complete response there.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thanks!

Comment: is there a dynamic solution to a variable "x" number of images (not just 3, 33%) ?

Comment: Mabey there is, but it's a more complex solution, if you post a question regarding this, I might try to create something.

Comment: @paulalexandru, the original question does ask for "N frames slide by side" so really it would be the real answer to this question.

Comment: @tehlivi, yes so what is the problem because I don't understand.He asked for N frames, but in his picture attached to the question 3 frames are displayed. If you want to have 4,5,6,..N all you need to do is to adjust the css values, it's that simple.

Comment: @paulalexandru If you updated your fiddle to show 4 instead or 3, you will need to change the js, html, and css. The js only displays one additional image instead of two.

Comment: @tehlivi Why would you show 4 insted of 3 since in the image attached to this question 3 images are displayed not 4? If you want 4, you change the code to display 4, what is the problem? The principle matters bro.

Comment: @paulalexandru I was just using 4 as an example. I understand the picture shows 3. However, OP wrote N. You said all you have to do to increase the amount of images was to just change the CSS which is not complete information for anyone else who may come to this question. The version of Bootstrap is out of date anyway for newer carousels. (I wish we could just get rid of all carousels forever)

Comment: @tehlivi, anyone who has minimum knowledge of javascript, css and html can figure it out based on my response. If you can't do that, than I suggest you post another question. There is no carousel with N elements. There is only carousels with 2,3,4... elements. So when you post a question you will write the exact number, not an N, because you know from the begining what your carousel will look like, how many elements will have. And this is the case for this example also, he knew that he needs 3 elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me out a lot. I am building a custom bootstrap theme for a drupal 8 site based on the Barrio theme. It doesn't have too many options when it came to customizing a carousel. The JS and CSS you've provided worked like magic. I had to modify the code a bit to suit my requirements but all in all its worked fantastically. Thank you so much @paulalexandru

Comment: How to stop carousel on last slide? don't want to append the first again.

Answer (score 10):

## Update 2019-03-06 -- Bootstrap v4.3.1

It seems the new Bootstrap version adds a `margin-right: -100%` to each item, therefore in the responsive solution given in the [most upvoted answer in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/6225838), this property should be reset, e.g.:

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
    margin-right: inherit;
}
```

A working [codepen with v4.3.1 in LESS](https://codepen.io/agap2_pt/pen/KEayQR).

Comment: God bless you ahaha

Comment: For anyone struggling with the above best selected answer, this answer, specifically the codepen link is working great using bootstrap v4.4.0.  
With a bit of tweaking you can easily get it working with 4 slides visible or whatever you need.
Thanks for posting.

Comment: A word of warning to anyone wanting to use the above - if you want to use indicators this is completely bugged.

Comment: This is by far the best solution for bootstrap ^4.3.1

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me. Very simple jQuery and CSS to make responsive carousel works independently of carousels on the same page. Highly customizable but basically a div with white-space nowrap containing a bunch of inline-block elements and put the last one at the beginning to move back or the first one to the end to move forward. Thank you `insertAfter`!

```js
$('.carosel-control-right').click(function() {
  $(this).blur();
  $(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').first().insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').last());
});
$('.carosel-control-left').click(function() {
  $(this).blur();
  $(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').last().insertBefore($(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').first());
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .carosel-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .carosel-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .carosel-item {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carosel-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
.carosel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
}
.carosel-inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.carosel-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.carosel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carosel-control-left {
  left: 15px;
}
.carosel-control-right {
  right: 15px;
}
.carosel-control:active,
.carosel-control:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carosel" id="carosel1">
  <a class="carosel-control carosel-control-left glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" href="#"></a>
  <div class="carosel-inner">
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" />
  </div>
  <a class="carosel-control carosel-control-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="carosel" id="carosel2">
  <a class="carosel-control carosel-control-left glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" href="#"></a>
  <div class="carosel-inner">
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" />
    <img class="carosel-item" src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" />
  </div>
  <a class="carosel-control carosel-control-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, tiny giant, can you please help with me 'carousel-indicators' in your answer. and auto slide feature enable/disable.

Answer (score 5):

Natively it is overly complicated and messy to achieve this just with [Bootstrap 3.4 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#carousel) and [Bootstrap 4.5 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/) javascript component features.

OK so you do not want *yet* another jQuery plugin... I get that.

In my opinion if you're already forced to use jQuery in your project, you might as well have a decent jQuery carousel plugin with lots powerful options.

### [slick.js - the last carousel you'll ever need - Ken Wheeler](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```txt
         _ _      _       _
     ___| (_) ___| | __  (_)___
    / __| | |/ __| |/ /  | / __|
    \__ \ | | (__|   < _ | \__ \
    |___/_|_|\___|_|\_(_)/ |___/
                       |__/
```

### *It truly is the last jQuery carousel plugin you will ever need.*

Here are minified [slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) distribution sizes...

- [slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css) - 1,369 bytes (4 KB on disk)
- [slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js) - 43,881 bytes (45 KB on disk)

Some scenarios you may be faced with...

- Unfortunately if you are just pulling distributed Bootstrap 3 or 4 `js` and `css` minified files from a CDN or where ever, then yeah it's another bulky jQuery plugin added to your website network requests.
- If you are using NPM, Gulp, Bower or whatever you can just exclude Bootstraps `carousel.js` and `carousel.scss` vendors to reduce the final compiled sizes of your `css` and `js` files. Excluding all unused Bootstrap `js` and `scss` vendors will help reduced your final compiled output files anyway.

Added bonuses using [slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)...

- Touch/swipe to scroll carousel on devices (you can drag on desktop too)
- Define carousel options for each responsive breakpoint
- Set `mobileFirst: true` or `false` to handle responsive breakpoint direction
- Set how many slides (columns) you wish to show or scroll (define for each breakpoint)
- Vertical and horizontal carousels
- `.on` events for everything
- Loads of options

---

### Bootstrap 3 multi column slick carousel example

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/RwogBJP) links below to test examples responsively...

- [codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/GRNEBXo](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/GRNEBXo) - `scss` example with Bootstrap 3 style arrows and dots
- [codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/RwogBJP](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/RwogBJP) - same code below simplest example...

```js
// bootstrap 3 breakpoints 
const breakpoint = {
  // extra small screen / phone
  xs: 480,
  // small screen / tablet
  sm: 768,
  // medium screen / desktop
  md: 992,
  // large screen / large desktop
  lg: 1200
};

// bootstrap 3 responsive multi column slick carousel
$('#slick').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  draggable: true,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  speed: 1000,
  
  mobileFirst: true,
  
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xs,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.sm,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.lg,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
/* .slick-list emulates .row */
#slick .slick-list {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

/* .slick-slide emulates .col- */
#slick .slick-slide {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#slick .slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery 3.3 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap 3.4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- slick 1.9 -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap 3 responsive multi column slick carousel example -->

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="float:left!important;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Slick in Bootstrap 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text pull-right" style="margin:15px!important;">
      <a class="navbar-link" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/" target="_blank">Slick Github</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slick">

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style="margin-top:0;">Article title</h3>
            <p>Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

### Bootstrap 4 multi column slick carousel example

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/MWboBVQ) links below to test example responsively...

- [codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/XWNgYYR](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/XWNgYYR) - `scss` example with Bootstrap 4 style arrows and dots
- [codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/MWboBVQ](https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/MWboBVQ) - same code below simplest example...

```js
// bootstrap 4 breakpoints
const breakpoint = {
  // small screen / phone
  sm: 576,
  // medium screen / tablet
  md: 768,
  // large screen / desktop
  lg: 992,
  // extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200
};

// bootstrap 4 responsive multi column slick carousel
$('#slick').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  draggable: true,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  speed: 1000,
  
  mobileFirst: true,
  
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: breakpoint.sm,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.lg,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xl,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
/* .slick-list emulates .row */
#slick .slick-list {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

/* .slick-slide emulates .col- */
#slick .slick-slide {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#slick .slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery 3.5 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap 4.5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- slick 1.9 -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap 4 responsive multi column slick carousel example -->
    
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Slick in Bootstrap 4</a>
    <a class="nav-link d-none d-sm-inline" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/" target="_blank">Slick Github</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slick">

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" class="card-img-top" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris. Nullam sollicitudin arcu ac diam ornare, eget iaculis nisl accumsan.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View article</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.....it work in mine....
**code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="span4" style="padding-left: 18px;">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                 <div class="span4" style="padding-left: 18px;">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x180" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The most popular answer is right but I think the code is uselessly complicated.
With the same css, this jquery code is easier to understand I believe:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
  var item = $(this);
  item.siblings().each(function(index) {
    if (index < 4) {
      $(this).children(':first-child').clone().appendTo(item);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This works for me, although I'm experiencing that the different items are arranged vertically, rather than horizontally, while the animation still runs horizontally

Answer (score 2):

```js
    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        $(".item.active:nth-child(" + ($(".carousel-inner .item").length -1) + ") + .item").insertBefore($(".item:first-child"));
        $(".item.active:last-child").insertBefore($(".item:first-child"));
    });
```

```css
        .item.active,
        .item.active + .item,
        .item.active + .item  + .item {
           width: 33.3%;
           display: block;
           float:left;
        }
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width:800px;">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=3">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=4">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=5">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=6">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=7">
    </div>    
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.1/holder.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE 2022 - BOOTSTRAP 5 CAROUSEL WITH MULTIPLE ITEMS

You can manage this task absolutely with bootstrap 5 CSS customization

This is a fantastic tutorial from a fantastic web developer
[Bootstrap 5 Carousel Multiple Items Increment By 1](https://codingyaar.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items-increment-by-1/)

[image]

well done tutorial with intermediate live results change after change

If you wanna increase the size of the slice of the 4th card (I suggest this to give the user a better sharper hint that there is a following card), just reduce from 33.333333% to e.g. 30% this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner {
    display: flex;
  }
  .carousel-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working on mobile screens for me.

Comment: On my Android 10 with latest Firefox and Chrome it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solutions described here worked well. But I wanted to support window size (and layout) changes. The result is a small library that solves all the calculation. Check it out here: https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/BootstrapCarouselPageMerger

To make the script work, you have to add a new `<div>` wrapper with the class `.item-content`
directly into your `.item` `<div>`. Example:

```
<div class="carousel slide multiple" id="very-cool-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="item-content">
                First page
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="item-content">
                Second page
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage of this library:

```
socialbitBootstrapCarouselPageMerger.run('div.carousel');
```

To change the settings:

```
socialbitBootstrapCarouselPageMerger.settings.spaceCalculationFactor = 0.82;
```

Example:

As you can see, the carousel gets updated to show more controls when you resize the window. Check out the `watchWindowSizeTimeout` setting to control the timeout for reacting to window size changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code


 <div id="recommended-item-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend2.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend3.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend2.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img src="img/home/recommend3.jpg" alt="" />
                            <h2>$56</h2>
                            <p>
                                Easy Polo Black Edition
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left recommended-item-control" href="#recommended-item-carousel" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </a>
    <a class="right recommended-item-control" href="#recommended-item-carousel" data-slide="next"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your question and answers, and made a new responsive and flexible multi items carousel Gist. you can see it here:

https://gist.github.com/IVIR3zaM/d143a361e61459146ae7c68ce86b066e

Answer (score -1):

You can add multiple li in ol tag that has attribute as class with value  "carousel-indicators" and with data-slide-to has sequential values like 0 to 6 or 0 to 9.

than you just need to copy and paste the div which has attribute as class with value "item".

This works for me.

```
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel" class=""></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel" class="active"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel" class=""></li>
        <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#myCarousel" class=""></li>
        <li data-slide-to="5" data-target="#myCarousel" class=""></li>
        <li data-slide-to="6" data-target="#myCarousel" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img alt="First slide" src="images/carousel/11.jpg"
                class="first-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Second slide" src="images/carousel/22.jpg"
                class="second-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/carousel/33.jpg"
                class="third-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/carousel/44.jpeg"
                class="fourth-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/carousel/55.jpg"
                class="third-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/carousel/66.jpg"
                class="third-slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/carousel/77.jpg"
                class="third-slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#myCarousel"
        class="left carousel-control"> <span aria-hidden="true"
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> <span
        class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a> <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#myCarousel"
        class="right carousel-control"> <span aria-hidden="true"
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <span
        class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us a bootply ?? it doesn't work and I don't get what you want to do here??

Answer (score -1):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once/20008623#20008623) to above link i added 1 new thing called **show 4 at time, slide one at a time for bootstrap 3 (v3.3.7)**

**CODEPLY**:- https://www.codeply.com/go/eWUbGlspqU

**LIVE SNIPPET**

```js
(function(){
  $('#carousel123').carousel({ interval: 2000 });
}());

(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      // wrap around if at end of item collection
      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: none;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.left {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-1,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-2,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-3 {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-1 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (transform-3d), all and (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-2,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) and (transform-3d), all and (min-width: 992px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/d6d6d6/333&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>          
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002040/eeeeee&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/40a1ff/002040&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```