# Bootstrap 3 carousel to show 2 active items at once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Maybe this is simple, but I need to make a Bootstrap3 carousel that shows 2 items at the sm screen size, and one on xs. I don't care if it advances by one or two, but the markup gets populated dynamically, so we can't group 2 in a div with a class of 'item'.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-3-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once

Comment: @Rafa I looked and it's not a duplicate. My question regards showing 2 within the sm resolution, and one on the xs resolution. My question also specifically states that the markup can't be both placed within the "item" div, which was the solution on that link anyways.