# Bootstrap Carousel multi items on v3.3.x

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

i have discovered a way to use multiple items with Bootstrap carousel (http://www.bootply.com/94444), but this example it only works for an older version (v3.0.2). I have created a new bootply with the same code but using the latest version (v3.3.4) http://www.bootply.com/2hfE7EsmhN. The transition need to be one-to-one and not all the items.

I will apreciate it your help fixing this bug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/2101328

Comment: Thanks timgavin, i tried with your link but didn't work with v3.3.4!