# carousel-slider images size issues medium window size and in firefox browser issue

Tags: slider, carousel

Recently I have applied three images frame per on slide on my homepage. When Windows is in normal size, it is OK as below. But when in medium window size, the image size has problems as it become enlarged, event in mobile size in firefox browser.
I have done according to :
[Bootstrap carousel multiple frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-3-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once)

problem in firefox.
[image]

no problem in chrome.
[image]

Comment: Any ideas ?? Please help!!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? or public URL? So we debug the source?