# Bootstrap Carousel - Number of Items to Display on Different Resoultions

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I want to use the bootstrap carousel to display a different number of items at different screen resolutions.

For example:

1. I want to show details for a 3 contacts when the screen resolution is greater than 1000px
2. I want to show details for a 2 contacts when the screen resolution is between 600px and 999px
3. Finally  I want to show details for a single contact when the screen resolution is less than 600px

Thanks for any help in advance. I have been stuck on this for a few days now..

Answer (score 3):

Easy to implement solution adapted to Bootstrap 4. Will get count of elements from "data-" and breakpoints from JS.

```js
(function ($) {
 function calcStepSize(optionNode) {
  var breakM = 990; 
  var breakS = 768; 
  
  var width = $(window).innerWidth();
  
  if(width < breakS) {
   var key = 's';
  } else if(width < breakM) {
   key = 'm';
  } else {
   key = 'l';
  }
  
  var cnt = 1*optionNode.data("itemcount-"+key);
  
  return cnt > 0? cnt : 1;
 }

 function repartition(container, items, count) {
  container.children().remove();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   var cBlock = $('<div class="carousel-item" ></div').appendTo(container);
   var cInnerBlock = $('<div class="row"></div>').appendTo(cBlock);
                
   for(var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    var cIdx = (i + j) % items.length;
    
    cInnerBlock.append($(items.get(cIdx)).clone());
   }
  }
  
  container.children().first().addClass("active");
 }
 
 $('.carousel.multi').each(function(idx, El) {
  var carousel = $(El);
  var container = carousel.find('.carousel-inner');
  
  if(!container.children().first().hasClass('carousel-item')) {
   var items = container.children().clone();

   var lastSize = calcStepSize(carousel);
   repartition(container, items, lastSize);

   $(window).resize(function () {
    var cSize = calcStepSize(carousel);

    if(cSize != lastSize) {
     repartition(container, items, cSize);
     lastSize = cSize;
    }
   }); 
  } else {
   container.children().first().addClass("active");
  }
  
  carousel.carousel({
   interval: false
  });
 });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/imsky/holder/master/holder.js"></script>

<div class="container">

<div class="bd-example">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel multi slide" data-ride="carousel" data-itemcount-l="4" data-itemcount-m="3" data-itemcount-s="2" autostart="0">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#ccc:#755" class="img-fluid" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#7dd:#7dd" class="img-fluid" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#747:#444" class="img-fluid" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#ccc:#755" class="img-fluid" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#7dd:#7dd" class="img-fluid" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img src="holder.js/250x250/auto/#747:#444" class="img-fluid" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
 
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an **easier** solution. Add a special CSS class (ie:`active-next`) to show the items the same way the `active` class does. When the carousel updates the active slide, add the class to the next item(s). Then apply the special class only on larger widths using a media query.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Q26U8fJDbx

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-item.active-next {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#mySlider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  $e.removeClass('active-next');

  var $next = $e.next();
  if ($next.length===0){
      $next = $('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  }
  var $nextnext = $e.next().next();
  if ($nextnext.length===0){
      $nextnext = $('.carousel-item').eq(1);
  }
  $next.addClass('active-next');
  $nextnext.addClass('active-next');
});
```

[Demo Bootstrap 4](http://www.codeply.com/go/Q26U8fJDbx/bootstrap-4-slider)

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidden-sm` and `hidden-md` classes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: That's the point, I need to have 50 reputation to add a comment. This is why to provide any information I need to add an answer and wait for it to get upvoted, which is really inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , we need `item` class to display items in carousel , but for this approach we don't use `item` class in DOM, instead we create it, after window load, based screen resolution. Working perfectly for me.I can't go less that 768 px as per my requirement , so you can update as per your requirement.

**NOTE** : **Works only on page load , Not on window resize.**

JS

```js
  var itemscounttovisible = 1;
    var w = window.innerWidth;  
    console.log(w)     ;
    if (w > 768 && w <= 980)
        itemscounttovisible = 4;
    if (w > 980)
        itemscounttovisible = 5;
    if (w == 768)
        itemscounttovisible = 3;
    if (w < 768)
        itemscounttovisible = 2;
    $('.carousel ').each(function (index, Obj) {
        id = $(Obj).attr('id')
        myArray = $('#' + id + ' >.carousel-inner >a');
        for (var q = 0; q < myArray.length;) {
            var ElementsToBeWrapeed = myArray.slice(q, q + itemscounttovisible);
            if (q == 0)
                // first slide must be active
                $(ElementsToBeWrapeed).wrapAll("<div class='item active'></div>");
            else
                $(ElementsToBeWrapeed).wrapAll("<div class='item '></div>");
            q = q + itemscounttovisible;
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div id="MenuID" class="carousel slide  carousel-fade " data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="0">
        <div class="carousel-inner">           
            <a href="#">contact  1</a>
            <a href="#">contact  2</a>
            <a href="#">contact  3</a>
            <a href="#">contact  4</a>
            <a href="#">contact  5</a>          
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#MenuID" class="left carousel-control"><span class=" fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>
        <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#MenuID" class="right carousel-control"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
    </div>
```

**Update:**

I used `a` tag for each inner item and used the same in JS, you can use whatever element (span, div, etc) you want but don't forget use the same in line `myArray = $('#' + id + ' >.carousel-inner >a');` in place of `a`.