# how to create differently responsive carousel using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

So I wanted to create a slider with divisions inside a bootsrap carousel and did the following. However, how can i make it so that in screens below sm(of bootstrap), it becomes such that there are only two divisions in one carousel and a carousel slider is added making three sliders with two divisions each. For this example, say that the first slider will only have hello, and hello1, second slider hello2, hello3 and a new slider is added which contains hello4 and hello5.

Please do tell me how do do this using bootstrap or javascript or jquery.

For better reference, this is the example:https://www.franckmuller.com/#home-news

Thanks a lot !!

```css
.box{
        min-height: 300px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .r{
        background-color: red;
      }
      .g{
        background-color: gray;
      }
      .b{
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box r">Hello</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box g">Hello1</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box b">Hello2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box r">Hello3</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box g">Hello4</div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box b">Hello5</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.r {
  background-color: red;
}
.g {
  background-color: gray;
}
.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-2">
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
     <div class="row row-cols-sm-2">
      <div class="col pe-1 box r">Slide 1</div>
       <div class="col box g">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row row-cols-sm-2">
       <div class="col box r">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="col box g">Slide 4</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: not quite, what i wanted is when the screen is below 400px, out of three divisions in a slider, only two remain in the slider and the third division moves into the second slider and so on, such that there are only two divisions left in every slide. To better understand, please look into [this](https://www.franckmuller.com/#home-news), and go into responsive design to change it below 400px. :)

Comment: Ahh, if you want to go that route I would highly suggest going for a carousel library instead. They come with the options to choose how many items to display on certain screens. Bootstrap currently doesn't have that option and you'd have to understand how the bootstrap carousel works under the hood to hack together a solution, if you're good with JS you can go for it, but to be honest you'll save a lot time just using a library. Check: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372294/bootstrap-carousel-number-of-items-to-display-on-different-resoultions)