# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Multiple frames at once and slide by one

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Another question was asked on the same need ([that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-3-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once)) for bootstrap 3 but the proposed solutions don't work with Bootstrap 4.

The image of this post explains very well what I want.

[image]

And even more [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/94444).

How can I achieve this with Bootstrap 4 ?

Comment: I want multiple slide displayed at the same time (1, 2 and 3), and when I click next I want the slide 2 and 3 moved to the left a little and the 4 displayed (while the 1 disappear).

Comment: Note that the "bootstrap 3" question mentioned above also now has an amazing answer that covers Bootstrap 4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/413538  this really should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        $(".carousel-item.active:nth-child(" + ($(".carousel-inner .carousel-item").length -1) + ") + .carousel-item").insertBefore($(".carousel-item:first-child"));
        $(".carousel-item.active:last-child").insertBefore($(".carousel-item:first-child"));
    });
```

```css
        .carousel-item.active,
        .carousel-item.active + .carousel-item,
        .carousel-item.active + .carousel-item  + .carousel-item {
           width: 33.3%;
           display: block;
           float:left;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div class="container"> 
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=2">
    </div>    
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=3">
    </div>    
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=4">
    </div>    
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=5">
    </div>    
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=6">
    </div>    
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=7">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
   
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.1/holder.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code works but it also "glitchy". Try pressing the button left side next button (a.k.a. "previous") and you will see how weird the loading is. Is there anyway this can be improved?

Comment: agreed it is slow and glitchy... new slides take a while to load... and faster clicking makes it worse...

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2018**

Take a look at the [Bootstrap 4 docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/), and change the markup to Bootstrap 4:

http://bootply.com/SObwIezDyx

**Bootstrap 4 Beta** options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/171456

Comment: The result isn't what I want exactly. The transition isn't the same as the bootply I linked. I've already tried to change the markup.

Comment: Yeah, since the BS 4 transition animations are different, you may need to change the CSS... but it's still moving one at a time.