# Bootstrap4 multi-slide carousel with Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a dynamic multi-slide carousel with Django and Bootstrap.

Following the instructions laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152475/bootstrap-4-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once-and-slide-by-one), I've built the following but there is a problem with the html as the data from the model is not rendered on screen. (I am certain that it is a problem with the below as I have another similar carousel on the page which works fine).

template.html:

```
      <div class="container"> 
        <div id="modelCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            {% for modelInstance in modelData %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            <li data-target="#modelCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#modelCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#modelCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img data-src="{{ model.image }}">
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to explain it:

```
                     {% for modelInstance in modelData %}
          <img data-src="{{ model.image }}">
```