# How to make this in Javascript, jQuery or Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been trying to google this for hours, and I'm just totally clueless. I want to make something similar to the "Recent Vehicles" section at the bottom of this site, where you can click the arrow and the cars slide on and off the screen.

I have no idea what's the correct thing to google. I know it's not a slider or a carousel, because that's what I've been searching all night.

If someone can show me the basic idea of how to do this in Javascript, jQuery or Angular that would be awesome. Thanks in advance! =)

http://demo.themesuite.com/index.php?theme=Automotive-WP

Comment: It is a carousel. It just has more than 1 image showing at once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-3-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once

Comment: this is a really broad question. A question generally gives us an idea of what has been tried already via some code and specific questions. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dakusan it isn't showing more than one image at once in the viewport (though it definitely can) - it's animating blocks of text over top of the main image. The example uses [Slider Revolution](https://revolution.themepunch.com/).

Comment: can learn a lot by inspecting the live html in browser dev tools elements inspector. look at the structure and then look at corresponding style used. Also by poking through various script files you might encounter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a Carousel. A good one can be found at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/