# Bootstrap 4 - multi-item carousel responsive

Tags: carousel, responsive, items

I tried and tried to modify the samples over the internet for carousels with multiple items but none of them seems to work properly for bootstrap 4.

I have 5 images of 250x120, I would like to be able to display the carousel inside container div with 4 images (no image-fluid, just fixed size all the time), and when I resize to less screen space, be able to show only 3, and then 2, and 1 for small mobiles... rotating one at the time... is this so difficult?, please help, I'm a newbie...

Comment: You should  [edit] the question and show your code that reproduces the problem, and tell us what you observed and any error messages, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Multiple Items Carousel (several carousel items shown at once)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393210/bootstrap-4-multiple-items-carousel-several-carousel-items-shown-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

Add .d-none class to 3 the carousel item which you do not want to show on small screen. Then add d-block-sm, d-block-md and d-block-lg to the item you want to show on respective screen.