# Thumbnail Carousel - Single image sliding Showing Error. It's Sliding Full Slider

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm Using Thumbnail Carousel - Single image sliding [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/thumbnail-carousel-single-image-sliding), I Copy full Slider and add it in my website but now its sliding all images. my website full code it here and for more view visit [Here](http://knowy.co.in)

i want to Slide only one at one time but when i add it in my site its scrolling full slider at one time then show next slide help me!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000
    })
    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.left { left: -33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.right { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .next { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .prev { left: -33.33%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://knowy.co.in/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.knowy.co.in/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
 <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
        <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                    <div class="text-center">6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
    </div>
    <!--/carousel-inner-->
</div><!--/myCarousel-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Bootstrap are you using? After version 3.3.1 the Carousel is using CSS transform for the animation. See this answer:  [Bootstrap carousel multiple frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once/20008623#20008623)