# Bootstrap 4 Multi Carousel show 4 images instead of 3

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out how to make it show 4 images instead of 3.

[Based on this Code: Bootstrap 4 Multiple Item Carousel](https://www.codeply.com/go/FrzoIEKCdH/bootstrap-4-carousel-multiple)

Script JS

```
$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
transform: translateX(-25%)
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

and I've changed to this code

```
<div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
```

instead of this original code

```
<div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 4 cols, are 25% width (instead of 33%) change the CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%)
}
```

Also an additional item needs to be cloned into each slide. So the JS change is:

```
$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});
```

[Bootstrap 4.0.0 Demo - 4 slides, advance 1](https://www.codeply.com/go/YbRfxfTDN1)

*Note:* From alpha 6 (when the original question was asked) to **Bootstrap 4.0.0**, the active carousel-item changed to flexbox. Therefore, the same must be done for the neighboring items in the multi-carousel.

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}
```

Also see: [Bootstrap 4.1.0 (advance all 4 at once)](https://www.codeply.com/go/HDu8lT7NxJ)

Comment: Thank you very much!
It's working good, But the photo showing vertical one line.
I know if you see on Codeply, it won't show up like that.

Comment: I just noticed the original one is using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, I'm using Beta 2 .... that's why the photo image showing vertical. but where should I change to make horizon instead of vertical