# Doubling up this modified bootstrap 4 carousel only functions half correctly (scroll loop stops working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I found this great carousel modification [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once). When I try to put two on a single page however, the scroll stops working as intended. I've gotten them to act on the proper Carousel, BUT when it gets to the end, it no longer loops properly. It basically loops to empty then repopulates them all again. But I am trying to figure out how to get them to fluidly loop from 1 to 8 and back to 1 seamlessly.

[Here is how the single functions and i'm trying to get the double to function.](https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH/multi-carousel-single-slide-bootstrap-4)

Note: It only functions improperly when not in the single item view (mobile view). Looking to fix how it functions when 3 items are shown at col-md size. If you run code, test in full screen mode to see what i'm talking about).

```js
// JavaScript Document

$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /* show 3 items */
    .carousel-inner .active,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <!-- Font CDN -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- MY CSS FILE-->
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div> <!-- episodes carsoel div -->  


 <!------------------- START OF TOP RECENT CLIPS CAROUSELS CONTENT -----------------------------------> 
<div class="container">
    <div id="test" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div> <!-- clips carsoel div --> 



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../js/my_js_main.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work on multiple carousel instances in the same page, you need to only apply your code to that instance of carousel. For that purpose, you need to save current carousel in a variable (`$c` in the example below):

```
$c = $e.closest('.carousel-inner'),
```

and use it to limit the jQuery selectors to current carousel only, replacing `$(selector)` with `$(selector, $c)`:

```js
// JavaScript Document

$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', modCarousel);
$('#test').on('slide.bs.carousel', modCarousel);

function modCarousel (e) {

    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget),
        idx = $e.index(),
        itemsPerSlide = 3,
        $c = $e.closest('.carousel-inner'),
        totalItems = $('.carousel-item', $c).length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item', $c).eq(i).appendTo($c);
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item', $c).eq(0).appendTo($c);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <!-- Font CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- MY CSS FILE-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1850">
      <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div id="test" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2100">
      <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#test" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../js/my_js_main.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.