# Bootstrap carousel animations glitching

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel that displays `3 items at a time` and `advances by one`.

When I click the next button the items change but it seems that the 2nd and 3rd item disappears, the first item plays the animation to left and then they appear (it's not smooth I would like them all to play the animation/translate). Also when the 6th item (6th card) is leftmost there is card 7 on the middle but no card on the rightmost (should be card 1), similar when the leftmost card is 7, there are 2 gaps.

I'm new to bootstrap, but I need to do this for `school`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some CSS, I copied code from https://codepen.io/mandelakibiriti/pen/xQXyKQ but just pasting everything didn't work so I made some changes to the CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

    if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
      var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
      for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction == "left") {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(i)
            .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
        } else {
          $(".carousel-item")
            .eq(0)
            .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
  transition: none;
  margin-right: initial;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This carousel has many CSS problems, please use @Zim (@codeply-er) solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/8798220

If you found a glitch on the slide, you can use [How to add gap between images in carousel slider or remove glitch when slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563369/how-to-add-gap-between-images-in-carousel-slider-or-remove-glitch-when-slide) concept ( my own question )

```js
$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var minPerSlide = 3;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        transform: translateX(33.33%);
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        transform: translateX(-33.33%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
    transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>

<div class="container text-center my-3">
  <h2 class="font-weight-light">Bootstrap 4 - Multi Item Carousel</h2>
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=1">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=2">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=3">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=4">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=5">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="img-fluid col-12 col-md-4" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=6">
              </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <h5 class="mt-2">Advances one slide at a time</h5>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**CARD**

```js
$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var minPerSlide = 3;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        display: flex;
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
            transform: translateX(33.33%);
        }

        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
            transform: translateX(-33.33%);
        }
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
</style>

<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light">Bootstrap 4 - Multi Item Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">

                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=1" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=2" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=3" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=4" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=5" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="card col-12 col-md-4" style="width: 18rem; border-width: 0;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380?text=6" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5 class="mt-2">Advances one slide at a time</h5>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried your code, but it only shows me the one image out of three each time I go to next one. I would also need text below images and scale it up. I also tried JQuery code with "my" code and it transitions faster, but still the same problems: 2 images disappear and it doesn't add first element to the end when it should.

Comment: If I stay with your images for a while, this is how it looks in the browser: https://imgur.com/a/Tl2sOrD , 2 images are missing.

Comment: What, Please make new fresh HTML file and copy-paste my whole code in that, see result and you can also see results with pressing `run code snippet`

Comment: I copied just like you send, I only put JQuery inside <script> tag, but still 2 images are missing, I tried on Chrome and Edge browser. If i run code snippet it works.

Comment: so do you want to say, your code is not working but StackOverflow snippet works well?

Comment: Yes the snippet works, but if I open my html document it doesn't, I must be stupid.

Comment: I don't know, there are no errors, I tried including some scripts and links but it doesn't work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey, I managed to get it working, but now if I replace img with my card element it doesn't show it nad it scales up weirdly.

Comment: I added card, watch out snippet

Comment: Thank you very much, hopefully my last question would be how to make the whole carousel bigger (similar size to "mine") so it would be almost full width?

Comment: just remove `.container` class