# How to make bootstrap carousel with cards

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to make a bootstrap carousel with cards in my website. I have a code from [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/Q60wSmoJHO/bootstrap-4-carousel-card-slider).
The code I used is

```
<section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-md-right lead">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">

        <div class="row row-equal carousel-item active m-t-0">
            {% capture category_name %}{{ page.category }}{% endcapture %}
          {% for post in site.categories[category_name] limit:4 %}
 {% if post.url != page.url %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-2">
                    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                      {% assign image = post.content | split:"!-- ![header](" %}
      {% assign html = image[1] | split:") -->" | first %}
      {% if html and html != "" %}
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ html }}" alt="Carousel 1">
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block p-t-2">
                      <h4 class="card-title text-center " itemprop="name headline">{{ post.title }}</h4>
                      <div class="text-center">
                      <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="btn btn-info my-2 text-center shadow-sm text-white" role="button">View Now</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         {% endif %}    
{% endfor %}

        </div>

<div class="row row-equal carousel-item m-t-0">
    {% for post in site.categories[category_name] offset:3 limit:3 %}

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-2">
                    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                         {% assign image = post.content | split:"!-- ![header](" %}
      {% assign html = image[1] | split:") -->" | first %}
      {% if html and html != "" %}
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ html }}" alt="Carousel 4">
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block p-t-2">
                       <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info" itemprop="name headline">{{ post.title }}</h4>
                       <div class="text-center">
                      <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="text-center btn btn-info shadow-sm my-2 text-white" role="button">View Now</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

{% endfor %}
        </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

javascript

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    // manual carousel controls
    $('.next').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('next');return false; });
    $('.prev').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('prev');return false; });

})(jQuery);
```

and css

```
/* equal card height */
.row-equal > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.row-equal .card {
   width: 100%;
}

/* ensure equal card height inside carousel */
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.next, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* prevent flicker during transition */
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active.left, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active.right {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: flex;
}


/* control image height */
.card-img-top-250 {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I think I have some bootstrap.css problem. My css loaded at https://demo.justinechacko.in/css/main.css

But when I apply that to my site, I have some problems like,
1. Carousel indicators are fixed to left (In codeply page it is in right position).
2. Carousel width is not proper in mobile view, it positioned little bit left.
3.Also carousel give 3 cards at a time in mobile view(In codeply it shows only one card at a time).
[Here](https://demo.justinechacko.in) is my site.

Comment: Any way to show card one by one

Comment: Check my answer for all three problems is listed below.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution for First two points**

`1. Carousel indicators are fixed to left (In codeply page it is in right position).`

`2. Carousel width is not proper in mobile view, it positioned little bit left.
Above points`

> **Main.css** (Line no.: 947)    **Replace below class**

```
.row {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
/* margin-right: -15px; */
/* margin-left: -15px; */
}
```

> For 3<sup>rd</sup> point 
>   `I will say you implement the wrong thing for your card. You can not put your card in normal carousel For that you have to use` **Owl Carousel**`I gave line below`

[Owl Carousel Official Link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

[Owl Carousel Example Link](https://codepen.io/MrFhilips/pen/BKXeKW)

Comment: I tried, owl carousel in my site, but not giving images. https://demo.justinechacko.in/

Comment: Now working, I missed `rel="stylesheet"` for css files.;)

Comment: @Can you check carousel nav indicators. It is not working for all slide.