# Make Bootstrap slider 1 column < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this product slider made with bootstrap 3. On desktop it is looking how I want it, but when the viewport is `< 768px` I would like the products is shown one at a time like this:

[image]

How it is now the height of the products is very big since all 4 products are displayed at the same time. Does anybody have an idea if this is possible to do?

Best regards.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".wish-icon i").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("fa-heart fa-heart-o");
  });
 }); 
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background: #e2eaef;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 26px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
 margin: 30px 0 60px;
}
h2::after {
 content: "";
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 4px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background: #7ac400;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: -20px;
}
.carousel {
 margin: 50px auto;
 padding: 0 70px;
}
.carousel .item {
 color: #747d89;
 min-height: 325px;
    text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel .thumb-wrapper {
 padding: 25px 15px;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 6px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.carousel .item .img-box {
 height: 120px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.carousel .item img { 
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.carousel .item h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
}
.carousel .item h4, .carousel .item p, .carousel .item ul {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.carousel .thumb-content .btn {
 color: #7ac400;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #7ac400;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.carousel .thumb-content .btn:hover, .carousel .thumb-content .btn:focus {
 color: #fff;
 background: #7ac400;
 box-shadow: none;
}
.carousel .thumb-content .btn i {
 font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.carousel .carousel-control {
 height: 44px;
 width: 40px;
 background: #7ac400; 
    margin: auto 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.carousel .carousel-control:hover {
 background: #78bf00;
 opacity: 1;
}
.carousel .carousel-control i {
    font-size: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
 text-shadow: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.carousel .item-price {
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 2px 0;
}
.carousel .item-price strike {
 opacity: 0.7;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.carousel .carousel-control.left i {
 margin-left: -2px;
}
.carousel .carousel-control.right i {
 margin-right: -4px;
}
.carousel .carousel-indicators {
 bottom: -50px;
}
.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-indicators li.active {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 4px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-color: transparent;
}
.carousel-indicators li { 
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.carousel-indicators li.active { 
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.carousel .wish-icon {
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 z-index: 99;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #abb0b8;
}
.carousel .wish-icon .fa-heart {
 color: #ff6161;
}
.star-rating li {
 padding: 0;
}
.star-rating i {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #ffc000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Multiple Item Product Carousel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <h2>Featured <b>Products</b></h2>
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="0">
   <!-- Carousel indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>   
   <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item carousel-item active">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/ipad.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">         
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Apple iPad</h4>         
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$400.00</strike> <b>$369.00</b></p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/headphone.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Sony Headphone</h4>         
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$25.00</strike> <b>$23.99</b></p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/macbook-air.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Macbook Air</h4>         
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$899.00</strike> <b>$649.00</b></p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>        
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/nikon.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Nikon DSLR</h4>         
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$315.00</strike> <b>$250.00</b></p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item carousel-item">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/play-station.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Sony Play Station</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$289.00</strike> <span>$269.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/macbook-pro.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Macbook Pro</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$1099.00</strike> <span>$869.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/speaker.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Bose Speaker</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$109.00</strike> <span>$99.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/galaxy.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Samsung Galaxy S8</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$599.00</strike> <span>$569.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>      
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item carousel-item">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/iphone.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Apple iPhone</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$369.00</strike> <span>$349.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/canon.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Canon DSLR</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$315.00</strike> <span>$250.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/pixel.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Google Pixel</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$450.00</strike> <span>$418.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <span class="wish-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
        <div class="img-box">
         <img src="/examples/images/products/watch.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-content">
         <h4>Apple Watch</h4>
         <p class="item-price"><strike>$350.00</strike> <span>$330.00</span></p>
         <div class="star-rating">
          <ul class="list-inline">
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
           <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>      
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Carousel controls -->
   <a class="carousel-control left carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control right carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
   </a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See this [example](https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8) from the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once/20008623).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is that not only with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Conceptually it will work for Bootstrap 3 too