# How to remove the half image card and make it full in html,css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website for my college, but this image card thing messed up things, how can i make the background image of the card full rather than shown in the image.Please see through it

```css
element.style {
}
.item_service_card {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel, .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.48;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
user agent stylesheet
html {
    color: -internal-root-color;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
the following code is my html code for the card
<div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 1900px;"><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 350px; margin-right: 30px;"><div class="item_service_card">
     <div class="image_service">
      <img src="assets/images/sycon.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="describe_service">
      <h4 class="name_service">
       SYCon
      </h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipiscing elit. In risus magna, porta sit amet
      orci ultrices, condimentum facilisis. </p>
     </div>
     <div class="overlay">
      <h4 class="name_service">
       <a href="sycon.html">SYCon</a>
      </h4>
      <h6>Guide:</h6>
      <p><a href="single-team.html">Jak Rooney</a></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      In risus magna, porta sit amet orci ultrices.
      Praesent sed eros et sapien laoreet vehicula ac at arcu. Suspendisse et nulla sem.
      Vestibulum condimentum risus vitae quam fringilla,
      vitae congue sem mattis. Nulla accumsan nisl ac massa sodales gravida.</p>
     </div>
```

**The details**

[image]

I want to remove the half background in the image and make it full in the image area

Comment: Try to add width of 100% to image or set image url to the `.image-service` class div and make background-size to cover this will work exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by placing `image` as `background-image`
Add this to your css

```
.image_service{
background:url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg)center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
height:-webkit-fill-available;
}
```

```css
*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item_service_card {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
   -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
   touch-action: pan-y;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}

.owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
   position: relative;
}  

.image_service {
   background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg)center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 1900px;">
      <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 350px; margin-right: 30px;">
        <div class="item_service_card">
          <div class="image_service">

          </div>
          <div class="describe_service">
            <h4 class="name_service">
              SYCon
            </h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In risus magna, porta sit amet orci ultrices, condimentum facilisis. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay">
            <h4 class="name_service">
              <a href="sycon.html">SYCon</a>
            </h4>
            <h6>Guide:</h6>
            <p><a href="single-team.html">Jak Rooney</a></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In risus magna, porta sit amet orci ultrices. Praesent sed eros et sapien laoreet vehicula ac at arcu. Suspendisse et nulla sem. Vestibulum condimentum risus vitae quam fringilla, vitae
              congue sem mattis. Nulla accumsan nisl ac massa sodales gravida.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: If you are trying to make a carousel, then you can do that with Bootstrap itself, Check this [codeply: Multi slider carousel](https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8) with cards which was beautifully explained by skelly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/9380480) .You can adjust `col` and `transform:translateX(*%)` as per your requirement. For `col-sm-4` it would be `transform:translateX(-33.3%)` and for `col-sm-3` it would be `transform:translateX(-25%)`.

Comment: I have 10 cards like that, how can i change the .image servicfe for everyone

Comment: you can mention separate class for all the cards like `card1` `card2` etc for all the image holder `div` and then add the images in the background. By the way, are you trying to make a carousel with cards?

Comment: check the above answer, updated. If you feel that was helpful, please accept my answer