# How to turn a container div into content slider

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and I have made this div:

```
<div class="second-para">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="second-section">
                <div class="container mt-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 section-two-title">
                            <h1 class="text-center m-0 py-2">
                                Newest
                            </h1>
                            <h1 class="text-center m-0 py-2">
                                Courses
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                            <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7096/people-woman-coffee-meeting.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                                <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                            <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                                <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web .</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                            <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/262550/pexels-photo-262550.jpeg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                                <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

But as I mentioned out in the image, I need to add two icons at the right and left of the cards in order to browse more courses.

So it would be a dynamic content slider.

But I don't know how to do that, so I would really appreciate if you could help me with this...

And here is also the CSS part:

```
        .second-para{
            height:500px;
            background-color: #ffcc32 !important;
        }

        .second-section, .third-section, .fourth-section{
            padding-top:100px;
        }

        .card-section{
            border-radius: 2%;
        }

        .second-section img, .third-section img, .fourth-section img{
            height:150px;
            width:100%;
        }

        .second-section .item, .third-section .item, .fourth-section .item{
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
        }
        .second-section .item-card, .third-section .item-card, .fourth-section .item-card{
            transition:0.5s;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .second-section .item-card-title, .third-section .item-card-title, .fourth-section .item-card-title{
            font-size:15px;
            transition:1s;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .second-section .item-card-title i, .third-section .item-card-title, .fourth-section .item-card-title{
            font-size:15px;
            transition:1s;
            cursor:pointer;
            color:#ffa710
        }
        .second-section .card-title i:hover,.third-section .card-title i:hover,.fourth-section .card-title i:hover{
            transform: scale(1.25) rotate(100deg);
            color:#18d4ca;

        }
        .second-section .card:hover,.third-section .card:hover,.fourth-section .card:hover{
            transform: scale(1.05);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .second-section .card-text,.third-section .card-text,.fourth-section .card-text{
            height:80px;
        }

        .second-section .card::before, .card::after,.third-section .card::before,.fourth-section .card::before, .card::after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            transform: scale3d(0, 0, 1);
            transition: transform .3s ease-out 0s;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
            content: '';
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .second-section .card::before,.third-section .card::before,.fourth-section .card::before {
            transform-origin: left top;
        }
        .second-section .card::after,.third-section .card::after {
            transform-origin: right bottom;
        }
        .second-section .card:hover::before, .card:hover::after, .card:focus::before, .card:focus::after,.third-section .card:hover::before {
            transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        }
        .section-two-title, .section-three-title,.section-fourth-title{
            padding-top:5%;
        }
        .section-two-title h1, .section-three-title h1, .section-fourth-title h1{
            font-size:30px !important;
        }
```

Comment: I tried copying your code and it didn't end up looking like your screenshot. (With bootstrap@3)

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic The only difference is direction which is `ltr` instead of `rtl`. But does not change the question.

Comment: @memite7760 Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Also even if it's a great exercice I will recommend you to not reinvent the wheel and use a slider library like [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/) or directly the bootstrap's [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/).

Comment: yes, like memite7760 said its better not to reinvent the wheel and use stablized libraries like swiper.js. you can check out demos here - https://swiperjs.com/demos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use [Bootstrap's Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/)

You need custom code, however, to show multiple cards at once: [Bootstrap carousel multiple frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once)

See this CodePly for another example: https://www.codeply.com/p/0CWffz76Q9

```js
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623 */
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

window.addEventListener('resize', initCarousel);
initCarousel();

function initCarousel() {
  items.forEach((el) => {
    // number of slides per carousel-item
    const minPerSlide = getMinSlides();
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i = 1; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
      if (!next) {
        // wrap carousel by using first child
        next = items[0]
      }
      let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
      el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
      next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
  })
}

function getMinSlides() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069
  const width = Math.max(
    document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    window.innerWidth || 0
  )
  if (width < 576) return 1
  if (width < 768) return 2
  return 4
}
```

```css
.second-para {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ffcc32 !important;
}

.second-section,
.third-section,
.fourth-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.card-section {
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.second-section img,
.third-section img,
.fourth-section img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.second-section .item,
.third-section .item,
.fourth-section .item {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.second-section .item-card,
.third-section .item-card,
.fourth-section .item-card {
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second-section .item-card-title,
.third-section .item-card-title,
.fourth-section .item-card-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second-section .item-card-title i,
.third-section .item-card-title,
.fourth-section .item-card-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffa710
}

.second-section .card-title i:hover,
.third-section .card-title i:hover,
.fourth-section .card-title i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25) rotate(100deg);
  color: #18d4ca;
}

.second-section .card:hover,
.third-section .card:hover,
.fourth-section .card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.second-section .card-text,
.third-section .card-text,
.fourth-section .card-text {
  height: 80px;
}

.second-section .card::before,
.card::after,
.third-section .card::before,
.fourth-section .card::before,
.card::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale3d(0, 0, 1);
  transition: transform .3s ease-out 0s;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
}

.second-section .card::before,
.third-section .card::before,
.fourth-section .card::before {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.second-section .card::after,
.third-section .card::after {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.second-section .card:hover::before,
.card:hover::after,
.card:focus::before,
.card:focus::after,
.third-section .card:hover::before {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.section-two-title,
.section-three-title,
.section-fourth-title {
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.section-two-title h1,
.section-three-title h1,
.section-fourth-title h1 {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}


/* More Carousel code */

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}


/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623 */

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="second-para">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="second-section">
      <div class="container mt-2">
        <h1 class="text-center m-0 py-2">
          Newest Courses
        </h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7096/people-woman-coffee-meeting.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web .</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/262550/pexels-photo-262550.jpeg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7096/people-woman-coffee-meeting.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web .</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/262550/pexels-photo-262550.jpeg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7096/people-woman-coffee-meeting.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="item-card-title mt-3 mb-3">Sierra Web Development • Owner</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7357/startup-photos.jpg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web .</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 item">
                  <div class="card item-card card-block card-section">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/262550/pexels-photo-262550.jpeg" alt="Photo of sunset">
                    <h5 class="card-title  mt-3 mb-3">ProVyuh</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a company that builds websites, web apps and e-commerce solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```