# Customize Bootstrap 5 carousel on mobile (several items but not in a single row)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-5

Im facing on issue while Im trying to customize the carousel layout on mobile.
I want it to show every item of the carousel on mobile, instead of showing only one, but after trying to play with some CSS and JS, especially with the `display` `float` or `max-witdh` Im just starting to think it's not possible, or I don't know where to look / looking at the wrong place / properties.
I joined 2 pictures so you fellas can see what Im trying to achieve.

What Im trying to achieve :
[image: What Im trying to achieve]

What I have :
[image: What I have]

The sample html code is a pretty basic one, Im not including CSS since this one is here just for design purposes.

```
<div id="solutions-carousel" class="carousel slide d-block d-md-none">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="./img.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="./img.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="./img.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="./img.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="./img.png" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel-indicators">
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#solutions-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#solutions-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#solutions-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#solutions-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#solutions-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
 </div>
```

Any ideas ? Cheers (and sorry for the bad english).

Answer (score 0):

I think similar question and case has been answered before in another thread. i've found some reference that might help you, i'll give you some of the links.
[Another thread in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/13636434)

you can also play with this JS code:

```
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Disclaimer: those answer/code snippet are not mine. I got it from https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY by Maurice melchers