# How can I change my bootstrap rotating logo carousel from advancing 1 image at a time to 4? (Ex: when clicking new arrow make it go from 1-4 to 5-8)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I created a rotating logo module in Wordpress using a bootstrap carousel found here: https://codepen.io/alephx/pen/EmZKpd.  I have the carousel working as intended in terms of showing the logos and rotating but I am having trouble figuring out how to modify the script or code to make it so when it rotates it goes from showing images 1-4 to 5-8 (rather than going from 1-4 to 2-5 to 3-6 one at a time). Can anyone help me figure out what should change to make it so that clicking the arrows/letting the carousel auto rotate will move the logos/images by 4 instead of 1 at a time?

The carousel works to rotate logos/images 1 at a time when auto rotating or when clicking the advance/previous arrows. I want it to rotate 4 at a time.

I've tried to adjust the script and tried researching online but wasn't sure what determines how many images are rotated

```js
    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
```

```css
    .carousel-control {
      width: 4%;
    }

    .carousel-control.left,
    .carousel-control.right {
      margin-left: 15px;
      background-image: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .carousel-inner .active.left {
        left: -100%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .next {
        left: 100%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .prev {
        left: -100%;
      }
      .active>div {
        display: none;
      }
      .active>div:first-child {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px) {
      .carousel-inner .active.left {
        left: -50%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .next {
        left: 50%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .prev {
        left: -50%;
      }
      .active>div {
        display: none;
      }
      .active>div:first-child {
        display: block;
      }
      .active>div:first-child+div {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .carousel-inner .active.left {
        left: -50%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .next {
        left: 50%;
      }
      .carousel-inner .prev {
        left: -50%;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width:767px) {
      .carousel-inner>.item.active,
      .carousel-inner>.item.next.left,
      .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right {
        left: 8%;
      }
    }

    .col-md-offset-3 {
      margin-left: 0%;
      width: 70%;
    }

    #right-carousel-control {
      content: '';
      background: url(http://sitexstaging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/right-arrow.webp);
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-size: 50px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-right: -50px;
    }

    #left-carousel-control {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
      transform: scaleX(-1);
      background: url(http://sitexstaging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/right-arrow.webp);
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-size: 50px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-left: -50px;
    }

    @media (max-width:600px) {
      #left-carousel-control,
      #right-carousel-control {
        width: 40px
      }
    }
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="display:flex; justify-content:center;flex-wrap:wrap;">
    
    
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h3 style="padding-bottom:30px;">Trusted Partners</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="9000" id="myCarousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=1">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=2">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=3">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=4">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=5">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=6">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=7">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x180?text=8">
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    
              <a class="left carousel-control" id="left-carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" id="right-carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the PHP with RENDERED HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan thank you. I edited and the code snippet now runs. Appreciate any help here. You will have to expand the snippet to see the 4 logos at once per slide like I referenced

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. do you know how to change the amount scrolled when the carousel rotates or advances from 1 to 4 at a time?

Comment: Seems it is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once)