# How to make the bootstrap next and prev buttons in the carousel work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Recently got interested on bootstrap 5 for my website design. I decided to add a carousel for my coffee items that will show only 3 products at same time when the right and left arrow buttons are clicked.

My current html container class is showing 3 items but when I press the buttons it doesn't move and show my 4th item. I kind of want it to show the 4th item when i press the left and right or next and prev button while maintaining 3 items shown in the carousel

Here is my carousel html block:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="carousel-container">
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <h1 class="text-white fw-bold mb-3 mt-3" style="text-align: center;">Popular Now</h1>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                          <!-- First carousel item -->
                          <div class="product-item">
                              <div class="product-info bg-dark text-light p-3">
                                  <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('/image/latte.jpg');"></div>
                                  <div class="product-text">
                                      <h5 class="mb-3">Latte Art Coffee</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-2">With Milk</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0 price-container">
                                        ₱ 60<span class="price-space"></span><button class="plus-btn">+</button>
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Second carousel item -->
                          <div class="product-item">
                              <div class="product-info bg-dark text-light p-3">
                                  <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('/image/espresso.jpg');"></div>
                                  <div class="product-text">
                                      <h5 class="mb-3">Espresso Coffee</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-2">With Milk</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">₱ 70<span class="price-space"></span><button class="plus-btn">+</button></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Third carousel item -->
                          <div class="product-item">
                              <div class="product-info bg-dark text-light p-3">
                                  <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('/image/mocha.jpg');"></div>
                                  <div class="product-text">
                                      <h5 class="mb-3">Mocha Coffee</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-2">With Chocolate</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">₱ 80 <span class="price-space"></span><button class="plus-btn">+</button></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Fourth carousel item (hidden initially) -->
                          <div class="product-item d-none">
                              <div class="product-info bg-dark text-light p-3">
                                  <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('/image/affogato.jpg');"></div>
                                  <div class="product-text">
                                      <h5 class="mb-3">Affogato</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-2">With Milk</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">₱ 90 <span class="price-space"></span> <button class="plus-btn">+</button></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- End carousel items -->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-controls-container">
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

my bootstrap link:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

my bootstrap script:

```
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

I tried adding a JavaScript function but still I get the same result:

/js/script.js

```
// Initialize the Bootstrap Carousel component without waiting for the entire document to load
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleControls');
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
  interval: false, // Disable automatic sliding
  wrap: false // Disable looping of carousel items
});

// Show/hide the fourth carousel item based on slide events
myCarousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
  var slideFrom = event.detail.from;
  var slideTo = event.detail.to;
  var items = myCarousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');

  // Hide the fourth item if sliding from the first item
  if (slideFrom === 0) {
    items[3].classList.add('d-none');
  }
  // Show the fourth item if sliding to the first item
  if (slideTo === 0) {
    items[3].classList.remove('d-none');
  }
});
```

script in my html:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

this is the 4th item i want to show when the arrows are clicked left or right:

```html
<!-- Fourth carousel item (hidden initially) -->
                          <div class="product-item d-none">
                              <div class="product-info bg-dark text-light p-3">
                                  <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('/image/affogato.jpg');"></div>
                                  <div class="product-text">
                                      <h5 class="mb-3">Affogato</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-2">With Milk</p>
                                      <p class="mb-0">₱ 90 <span class="price-space"></span> <button class="plus-btn">+</button></p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

Comment: Some clarification is needed. When you say "I kind of want it to show the 4th item when i press the left and right or next and prev button while maintaining 3 items shown in the carousel", do you mean something like this: 1) initial display: items 1, 2, 3 2) clicking on `right`: items 2, 3, 4, 3) clicking on `right`: items 3, 4, 1, and so on?

Comment: hello, sorry for the late notice. Yes this is what I want to describe how I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you initialize your script before bootstap.

Try this:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for this. but the issue is still there sadly

Comment: @PhyroNewbie just noticed, you've added different versions of bootstrap. Try to remove first

Comment: already change it to needed version of bootstrap. can you further help me with it? its still not working and showing the fourth item which is the Affogato Coffee

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008623/7196495 have you tried this?

Comment: your var items should be : var items = myCarousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item .product-item')